# Bluetooth Low Energy - notifyCharacteristicChanged() does not update the descriptor value

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor, gatt

I have the following problem - I must change the descriptor (BluetoothGattDescriptor) in my characteristic (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) dynamically as my application works.

Unfortunately function notifyCharacteristicChanged() from BluetoothGattServer updates only value of the characteristic (looked up this function in the Andoird sources - https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.java), it ignores the descriptors.

My descriptor is read only once - when the connection is established. But I want to change it dynamically and reconnection every time is not an option here.

Adding two services or characteristics with the same UUID but different descriptors did not solve the problem - distinguishing them was not possible.

Anyone faced similar problem?

This is the code:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic bc = mBluetoothGattServer.getService(service).getCharacteristic(characteristic);
bc.setValue(data);
bc.getDescriptor(descriptor).setValue(new byte[]{0, 0});      <- no effect here
mBluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(connectedDevice, bc, false);
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do indicates your system suffers from bad design.

Characteristic descriptors are *generally* not meant to be changed over time by the Server's Host. Either way, in the spirit of BLE, it's only the Characteristic's **value** that can be notified to Clients.

The fact that you want to change it "dynamically" is just not right. Why do you?

If it has some important, meaningful data for your entire application, then create a new Characteristic.

A Characteristic Descriptor should only have the purpose of "explaining" how the Characteristic's value is supposed to be used, its format, its units etc.

Comment: Yes - this is at least a violation of the spirit of things, and quite likely the actual spec as well.  Perhaps they can have one characteristic that functions as a mode indicator or effectively a pointer to a currently appropriate one of several others, which should then be read.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer above for details. It was too long for a comment here.

Comment: @j.wiszowaty I'm answering here too: The HID Service specifically has **2 special Characteristics for keyboard report and mouse report**. Use those!!!